# HTML checkbox default

Tags: html, get

I have an HTML checkbox:

```
<input name="foo" id="foo" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

In my application, the checkbox should retain its `checked` status between form submits (`method=GET`), so my server-side code simply inserts the `checked` status flag if `foo` is found in the GET-data.

```
if "foo" in GET:
     = ' checked'
else:
     = ''
```

This is fine, and it works. However, the logic breaks down when I want the checkbox *checked by default*, because, from the server side, I am unable to differentiate between:

- the checkbox being unchecked by the user (`"foo" not in GET`) – in which case I should leave the checkbox unchecked.
- the user having visited the form for the first time and having not yet specified a value (*also* `"foo" not in GET`) – in which case I should check the checkbox by default.

I have considered using a `hidden` `input` that tells me whether this is a user-submit or not, but this messes up the URL since the data is passed in `GET`. I feel there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the server knows:

- All the (checkbox)inputs
- Which of these inputs are default checked

You can reverse the test:

- Test all known server-side fields (loop server-side data to...)
- See if they exist in the received data (... test client-data (every time))
- If the are checked by default, and not in the data, you know the user unchecked it